# How to reflect changes made in xlsx files?

Tags: r, excel, data-wrangling, wrangle

I'm trying to wrangle data from a shared excel file in one drive. I have synced one drive to my macbook so I'm easily able to access it in r with a path. I have the following code:

```
my_data <- "Users/B.../Folder/my_file.xlsx"
excel_sheets(path = my_data)
```

I'm not sure if more of my code would be necessary for this question, but I just go on to organize the data:

```
str(list_all)

sheets <- excel_sheets(path = my_data)

list_all_2 <- lapply(sheets, function(x) read_excel(path = my_data, sheet = x))

str(list_all_2)

my_data_2 <- rbind.fill(list_all_2)
str(my_data_2)
```

My issue comes at this point. As I said, I'm using data from a shared excel file and I want to be able to run this code a few times for analyses that will reflect the newly changed/added data. When I go into the excel file and change something, it isn't reflected in the df in my working directory so I'm not sure it's working/ways in which to fix this.

Comment: @stefan_aus_hannover sorry could you explain more

Comment: A script is going to run once. Are you trying to trigger a rerun of the script when the excel file is saved? I think you'll need some sort of additional tool to stay running and check for changes.

Comment: Are you saying that you are re-running the script AFTER you have made the change, and it still seems to be the same data as you had done BEFORE the change is made?

Comment: @Phil yes exactly!

Comment: @camille, yes this could be. I'm fairly new to this so I thought by re-running it it would be re-doing and re pulling the data and would therefore be updated